# Erro na compilação Ionic e Cordova: An error occurred while running cordova build android --debug (exit code 1):

Tags: angularjs, ionic, apache-cordova, cordova-plugin

Estou tentando compilar minha aplicação, mas dá a mensagem a seguir::

```
> cordova build android --debug
× Running command - failed!
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android --debug (exit code 1):


        Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
        C:\apps\vovocooks-v10\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:\apps\vovocooks-v10
        add to body class: platform-android
        ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Ramos\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
        JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_144
        Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
        :wrapper

        BUILD SUCCESSFUL

        Total time: 11.495 secs
        Subproject Path: CordovaLib
        null
        The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use
        Task.doLast(Action) instead.
                at build_455elprf89385ghd5v1ztjpv5.run(C:\apps\vovocooks-v10\platforms\android\build.gradle:139)
        org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23+
        The JavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0.
        Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
        The TaskInputs.source(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Please
        use TaskInputs.file(Object).skipWhenEmpty() instead.

        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

        * What went wrong:
        A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
        > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_armv7DebugApkCopy'.
            > Could not find com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.2.
              Searched in the following locations:

        file:/C:/Users/Ramos/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v13/26.0.2/support-v13-26.0.2.pom

        file:/C:/Users/Ramos/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v13/26.0.2/support-v13-26.0.2.jar

        file:/C:/apps/vovocooks-v10/platforms/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/support-v13/26.0.2/support-v13-26.0.2.jar
              Required by:
                  project :

        * Try:
        Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

        BUILD FAILED

        Total time: 14.626 secs
        Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

        * What went wrong:
        A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
        > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_armv7DebugApkCopy'.
            > Could not find com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.2.
              Searched in the following locations:

        file:/C:/Users/Ramos/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v13/26.0.2/support-v13-26.0.2.pom

        file:/C:/Users/Ramos/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v13/26.0.2/support-v13-26.0.2.jar

        file:/C:/apps/vovocooks-v10/platforms/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/support-v13/26.0.2/support-v13-26.0.2.jar
              Required by:
                  project :

        * Try:
        Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Já olhei as variáveis de ambiente, e parecem estar tudo certo, vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Android e o Java estão atualizados. O que pode ser?

Comment: Os métodos `Task.leftShift` e `TaskInputs.source` foram descontinuados, use os métodos `Task.doLast`, `TaskInputs.file`. O método `JavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir()` foi removido da versão `4.0` do Gradle.

Comment: @WéllingthonM.deSouza Não entendi. Fiz uma busca em meus arquivos dos métodos mencionados, não encontrei nada. Teria como explicar melhor? Obrigado.

Comment: Veja no arquivo `build.gradle`, `C:\apps\vovocooks-v10\platforms\android\build.gradle:139` linha 139.

Comment: Esses métodos são referentes ao `Gradle`, sua versão dele é mais recente, então está te informando que os métodos foram descontinuados, então você terá que configurar o arquivo `build.gradle` do *gradle*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could not find com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.2.

A partir da versão 26 das bibliotecas de suporte, verifique se a seção de repositórios inclui o endereço do repositório do Google.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

> The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
>
> The TaskInputs.source(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Please use TaskInputs.file(Object).skipWhenEmpty() instead.
>
> The JavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0.

As linhas acima encontrada no `registro de depuração` ( Log ), está informando que :

- O método Task.leftShift(Closure) foi obsoleto e está agendado para ser removido no Gradle 5.0. Por favor, use `Task.doLast(Action)` em vez disso. *( Tradução livre )*.
- O método TaskInputs.source(Object) foi obsoleto e está programado para ser removido no Gradle 4.0. Use `TaskInputs.file(Object).skipWhenEmpty()` em vez disso. *( Tradução livre ).*
- O método JavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir() foi obsoleto e está agendado para ser removido no Gradle 4.0. *( Tradução livre ).*

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado @Wéllingthon